# Remove Vertical line in expander view Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the windows phone toolkit and the expander view. By default the expander view has a vertical line on the left side, Can i remove that default vertical line? thanks

Comment: Hi , I'm having same problem, can you provide me a working sample? thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modify Expanderview Style,

```
 <Style TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseInOut" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Expanded">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Collapsed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="ExpandedToCollapsedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1.0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.0"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0.0"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-35"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandabilityStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expandable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NonExpandable">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandableContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Line">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NonExpandableContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Expander" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <Line x:Name="Line" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="NonExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeader}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Canvas x:Name="ItemsCanvas" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,0,0,0" Opacity="0.0" Grid.Row="2">
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateY="0.0"/>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Presenter"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not able to implement this code. Any working example will do magic for me. Please post one in detail. Thanks..!

Comment: @ameyarote: Just remove this line from above code "<Line x:Name="Line" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1"/>"